# How do I define a numeric multi-value field in the Schema.xml for Solr?

Tags: solr, schema, numeric

I have decimal values such as 100.11, 200.22.   The database has the field defined as 100.11 200.22. I'm using double as the tag in the database field.  I tried defining the field as type="double" in the schema, but when I try creating the index it fails.  If I define it as type="text" then it works, but then i can't do solr query on it like looking for a range of numbers.  It treats as text in my solr query.

In my schema.xml I have:

```
<field name="ProviderCompensation" type="double" indexed="true" multiValued="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Comment: Have you defined which class to use for field type named double?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is "telling Solr which class to use when type is named as double". For details on the field types provided by `Solr` have a look [here](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr)

You need to define the class in the `types` section something like -

```
<fieldtype name="double"  class="DoubleField"/>
```

You can also, on the basis of your requirements, define fields as mentioned [here](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Defining+Fields)